# Rendering Images from node Backend on React App in production mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I designed an app in which the frontend is React(port 3000) and Backend Express(port 3500), using cors package I was able to share resources between them like rendering Images from the express on React. However in production, I discover that the images are not displaying. I guess the problem is from the link for SRC attribute of IMG tag in production? since development

Comment: Please give a [mcve], there is absolutely no information here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `express.static` for serving files you can use this code for the files located in ./public :

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

and you can access to it by using this code in react :

```js
<img src='localhost:3500/static/img.jpg'/>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response!  However I mean in production environment(heroku) since I would not be connecting to local host but a hosted server I guess it might look like 
<img src='https://exampleheroku/static/image/IMG.jpg>.  Also In a tutorial I watched  heroku build pack for create-react-app was used to build before deployment then under production environment the static folder was exposed like 
    app.use(express.static('build')). 'build' is the folder I pushed to heroku.